# MVC View replace comma for dot

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I got this code in my create view, i got this error : 
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).mask is not a function

```
    @model DO.Domain.Model.FileGrossMarginModel

    @{
        Layout = null;
    }



<div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalCreateOrEditTitle">@(Model == null ? "Add New" : "Edit") File Gross Margin</h4>
    </div>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("_CreateOrEdit", "FileGrossMargin", FormMethod.Post))

{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            @if (Model != null)
    <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Value, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-3 " })
                <div class="col-sm-9" id="grossmargin">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Value, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-circle percent" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Value, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
</div>}

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.13.4/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/assetsClean/global/plugins/jquery.validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/assetsClean/global/plugins/jquery.validate/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>





<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($(".modal-body form"));

    $('.percent').mask('##9,00');
    $(".percent").blur(function () {
        if (parseFloat($(this).val().replace(',', '.')) > 100) {
            $(this).val('100,00');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Value is a percentage form
My problem is i want to replace in the mvc forms the comma for a dot automatically in => model.Value enter code here

Comment: did you try to add a replace on the model.Value?

Comment: @William yes, i tried use //parseFloat($(".money").val().replace(',', '.')

Comment: @PedroSantos, try using .replace(",", "."); instead.

Comment: @Dimitri not working..

Comment: you should put all your cshtml file

Comment: @HienNguyen done

Comment: where is Valueenter field?

Comment: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Value, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control input-circle money" } }

Comment: @PedroSantos Try to do this, var value = $(this).val().replace(',', '.'); and after that var parsedValue = parseFloat(value); and see what is in there using alert(value); and alert(parsedValue);

Comment: @PedroSantos I was telling to use @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Value.Replace(",", ".")